# Sharp font edges in Visual Studio Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I re-installed my PC. I am noticing sharp font edges in the text editor of Visual Studio 2008. It looks worse when I change the fint size to 11 and above. I also tried several fonts, same thing. I am currently on 'Consolas'. Any ideas wher I should look?

Comment: not programming related, but have you enabled clear type or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get closed but assuming you are on XP and have an LCD monitor (it doesn't help much on CRT), you need to install the [ClearType Tuner PowerToy](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypePowerToy.mspx). Vista and 7 shipped with clear type enabled by default so if you are on one of these than the problem is elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

As Naveen noted, your problem is related to ClearType.  Instructions will vary based on your operating system.  For XP, use the [online tuner](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/Step1.aspx).  For Vista and Windows 7, it is in the control panel.  (For Windows 7, go to Control Panel > Fonts > Adjust ClearType text)

I should also add, ClearType only works on an LCD monitor because it is specific to how an LCD panel manages its pixels.  If you are still using a CRT, you'll have to live with it.